# Minimization of a sum of logarithms

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

If $A = (a_1, \dotsc, a_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector, we define the function $f_A: \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ by $$f_A(x)= \sum_{i=1}^n \log(1 + |x - a_i|)$$
I have shown that the minimum of $f_A$ is reached for $x \in \lbrace a_1, \dotsc, a_n \rbrace$. This result can be obtained easily by considering that the function is piecewise concave on the $(a_i, a_{i+1})$ segments (considering ordered $a_i$). The concavity can be shown for example by taking the second derivative on the segment (inside a segment, the sign of $x - a_i$ is constant).
However, it is not necessarily reached at the median value.

Is there any way to find analytically the value of the argmin of such function? Thank you!

Comment: I wonder if the function always has at most one local maximum?

Comment: @quasi Good point: it doesn't. Take for instance a symmetric vector $A = (-1, 1)$.

Comment: No, I asked about local max count, not local min count.

Comment: Two specific questions: (1) Do you know of an example which has more than one local max point? (2) Do you know of an example which has more than two absolute min points?

Comment: @quasi I believe that for (1) take $A=(-2,-1,1,18)$(although it is only from look, I didn't check analytically). I believe that for (2) the answer is no but, again, I didn't prove it(yet)

Comment: @Holo: Yes, that example works to resolve my question $(1)$. Thanks. Notice though, if you use the product version as in Rushabh Mehta's initial comment, the function is not concave between $x=1$ and $x=18$ (it has an inflection point).